# Why is Visual Studio breaking on an unhanded exception running unit tests?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, unit-testing, exception, unhandled-exception

maybe someone is able to explain me why I'm having unhandled exceptions when running unit tests? Is not supposed the environment to handle all the exceptions and just set the test to failed?

This can be related to the fact that the unit tests are calling unmanaged code thru C++/CLI?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Just to clarify, the problem is not having an exception. The problem is the exception not causing the unit test to fail and going to execute the next unit test.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing quite as nasty as an AccessViolation exception, only StackOverflow is worse.  I can make out "communication", that unmanaged code probably runs in a thread that neither the CLR nor the test runner knows anything about.  Very limited options there, no way to make a thread like that simply seize to exist.

It's a memory corruption problem, the debug allocator in the CRT fills freed blocks of memory with 0xfeeefeee.  That's not kosher btw, you should only run unit tests on the Release build.

Comment: Mmmmm, in this situation you're rigth, the exception has been generated in a thread created from unmanaged code (using the ACE library). So in this scenario this is the expected behaviour? Any way to change it? Thanks a lot. (The bug is known and its fixed but the fix has not been released yet so I need to run the UT with that bug for a while).

Comment: Good to me rigth once in a while.  Yes, expected, can't make that thread just disappear.  Short from running unit tests on Debug built code, keeping it running on known and fixed bugs makes very little sense either.  What the hell are you doing?  You know the bug, you know the bug fix, why would you want to prove that the bug existed a week ago?  Some sense of pragmatism is warranted here.  If you found the bug fix, stop proving to yourself that you're cool, it isn't productive.

Comment: Life is not as easy as you think, we run unit tests over the deliverables we give. We do not fix all the bugs we find (at least not immediately) as fixing a bug in a low priority area could create a bug at a high priority area (we are talking about medical software). I would say that it's not a good idea to take for fools others when you lack a lot of information. Thanks anyway for your help.